# A smooth curve is locally, in some coordinate system, a curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, curves, implicit-function-theorem

My professor introducedthe next  theorem in class, using Implicit function theorem:
Let $f: U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R} $ be a $C^1$ function, such that $f'(\underline{p}) \neq 0$ .
Then, there is a local coordinate system, where $f(\underline{y})=f(\underline{p}) +y_1 $

Now comes a question, that  I feel it can be proved using the mentioned  theorem:
A smooth injective curve is locally a line.

I would live some help- I'm trying to make the curve graph to a function into the real line, but I think that  taking the last coordinate is not good enough .

Comment: Wasn't sure about how much answering my own question is ok- just wanted that others could enjoy that statement. If it's not ok, please comment and I'll delete the post.

Comment: It's totally OK to answer your own question; you can even accept the answer (although you won't get any points for it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the implicit function theorem, one can prove the theorem mentioned before, in a little different conditions:
Let $ f:U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}^m $, where m>n and f is smooth. If some point p in the domain of f holds: 
rank($ f'(\underline{p})$)=n, there is local coordinate system where locally f(y)=f(p)+($y_1,...,y_n$,0,0,...,0).
Now, by taking n=1 , the rank is 1( the curve is smooth), hence we can apply that theorem.